# stability with eigenvalues on unit circle

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, control-theory, linear-control

I have designed a matrix ($A \in \Bbb R^{n\times n}$) that will converges the vector $x\in\Bbb R^{n\times 1}$ to its equilibrium point $ x^* \ne 0$. If i do not translate $x$ as $x'=x-x^*$, then

$ \lim_{k \to \infty} x(k+1) = Ax(k) \to x^* \neq 0.$

this (perhaps) means that not all the eigenvalues of $A$ are within the unit circle and at least one of the eigenvalues is on unit circle as $x(k) \not \to 0$?

This means that without the translation $(x'=x-x^*)$,  we cannot represent the asymptotic stability of the system, where $x^* \neq 0$ ?

DETAIL: In my case, the equilibrium point of the system is not known exactly and decided dynamically, so I cannot use the translation ($x'=x-x^{*}$) and the matrix $A$ designed without the translation has a single eigenvalue at unit circle. how can i show the asymptotic stability without using translation and one of the eigenvalue at unit circle.

Comment: I do not think I understand the question. When you say $x_k\to x_*$ you mean one particular initial state $x_0$ (it cannot converge to the same $x_*$ for all $x_0$, for example, $x_0=0$ gives zero). Thus, you cannot talk about asymptotic stability after the change $x'=x-x_*$ (asymptotic stability is convergence to zero for all initial states).

Comment: @A.Γ. But one could still call it Lyapunov stable, which is a weaker notion of stability.

Comment: sorry for being ambiguous, i assumed that if $x \in R^{x \times 1}$ implies that $x^* \in R^{n \times 1}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the operating point is decided dynamically, it all depends on the dynamics *how* the operating point is moved around. I see two possibilities:

- If you can write the dynamics of the operating point as a system of
  ODEs you can just include these in your original system. Then you
  check stability of this new system.
- If you have no ODEs for the operating point you have to treat its movement as an exogenous input, so you get a time varying system which you can check for stability.

If you post a concrete example, it might be possible to give more specific help.